# Upload de Imagen en SD App via REST

Tags: genexus

Genexus 15 build 107258 .NET

Tengo una aplicación *offline* que sincronizo con el servidor en forma manual. Tengo una `Transaction` con un atributo `Image` que corresponde a una foto que se toma en el dispositivo. Esa foto debe sincronizarse como el resto de los atributos de la `Transaction`. Ya logré sincronizar todos los atributos via REST menos la foto. Vi que hay un 
[documento](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15316,Procedures%20as%20REST%3A%20Sending%20blob%20data%20as%20input%20to%20the%20procedure,) en la *wiki* y estoy lo probando con un `Web Panel` que toma la ruta del archivo a subir del cliente, o sea algo como:

> C:\imagenes\imagen.jpg

y el server me da el siguiente error:

> [HttpException]: Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path
>   peligroso en el cliente (:).    en
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()    en
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext
>   context)

¿Cómo se le pasa el archivo al objeto `HttpClient`? Luego, cuando pase a hacerlo en SD, ¿hay que tener alguna consideración adicional?

Answer (score 2):

La sincronización automática lo que hace es subir primero los archivos (imágenes, audio, video, etc.) y luego cuando envía los datos envía identificadores en lugar de los binarios. Tu solución "a mano" supongo que debería hacer algo parecido.

La forma más fácil de subir una imagen es mediante la llamada a un `Procedure`, que reciba la imagen por parámetro:

```
parm(in:&someImage, out:&tempImageIdentifier);
```

El `Procedure` debería devolver algún tipo de identificador para luego saber cuál es la imagen.

Otra opción es mandar todo en un `SDT` como parámetro del `Procedure`, en ese caso se va a hacer el *upload* de todas las imágenes que haya de forma automática, y van a estar disponibles como miembros del `SDT` en el `Procedure` en el servidor.

Por ejemplo:

```
&sdt = new()
&sdtItem = new()
&sdtItem.Id = &id
&sdtItem.Image = &image
&sdt.Items.add(&sdtItem)
...
SendData(&sdt)   // este es el procedure que se expone como REST, tiene que tener Connectivity Support = Online
```

Fijate este documento (en inglés): [Procedures as REST: Using SDT as input to the procedure](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15315)

Comment: Estoy con la opcion del sdt que mencionas, pero al invocar el ws me esta dando esa HttpException `Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path peligroso en el cliente`

Comment: La opción del SDT que te decía **NO** es lo que dice el documento que pusiste más arriba... No deberías usar ese documento, el servicio REST que usa es interno, tal vez incluso haya que dar de baja ese documento. Agrego un ejemplo en la respuesta...

Comment: Ok uso el doc que envías. Ahora al consumir el webservice me da `{"error":{"code":"500","message":"El mensaje entrante tiene un formato de mensaje inesperado 'Raw'. Los formatos de mensaje esperados para la operación son 'Xml'; 'Json'. Esto se puede deber a que no se ha configurado un WebContentTypeMapper en el enlace. Para obtener más información, consulte la documentación de WebContentTypeMapper."}}`

Comment: Solucionado!  pude subir una imagen a través de un sdt recibido por parámetro acá hay detalles https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67187/webservice-rest-con-sdt-por-parámetro/67236?noredirect=1#comment123109_67236