# WebService REST con sdt por parámetro

Tags: genexus

Siguiendo el ejemplo que dice [aqui](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15315,Procedures%20as%20REST%3A%20Using%20SDT%20as%20input%20to%20the%20procedure,)
Tengo un ws rest que recibe un sdt:

```
parm(in:&sdtPrueba,out:&salida);

&salida="ok"
guardolog.Call(&Pgmname+"#valor:"+&sdtPrueba.ToJson().Trim())
```

Las propiedades del webservice son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el sdtPrueba que recibe es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para consumir al webservice hago lo siguiente:

```
     &servicio=&ServerProtocol+"://"+&ServerHost+&ServerBaseURLRest+"wsprueba"
//la url resultante queda asi: HTTP://192.168.10.169/webapp/rest/wsprueba
    &metodo="POST"
    &httpclient.Host = &serverHost.Trim()
    &httpclient.Port = &serverPort
    &httpclient.BaseUrl = &ServerBaseURLRest.Trim()
    &httpclient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')
    &sdtPrueba.sdtPruebaID=1
    &sdtPrueba.sdtPruebaTxt="Pruebaaaa"
    &body='{"sdtPrueba":'+&sdtPrueba.ToJson().Trim()+"}"
    &httpclient.AddString(&body)
    &httpclient.Execute(&metodo,&servicio)
    &status=&httpclient.StatusCode.ToString().Trim()
    &respuesta=&httpclient.ToString().Trim()
```

recibo como respuesta lo siguiente:

```
{"error":{"code":"500","message":"El mensaje entrante tiene un formato de mensaje inesperado 'Raw'. Los formatos de mensaje esperados para la operación son 'Xml'; 'Json'. Esto se puede deber a que no se ha configurado un WebContentTypeMapper en el enlace. Para obtener más información, consulte la documentación de WebContentTypeMapper."}}
```

Por lo que pude ver, el problema esta en como estoy pasando el `body`. Porque quitando el parametro sdt y quitando el `body` el webservice funciona perfectamente.

Necesito una mano con esto. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Bruno,

Podrías verificar que el nombre del parámetro sea exactamente igual al del JSON?

Es decir, para este body, deberías tener:

&body='{"sdtPrueba":'+&sdtPrueba.ToJson().Trim()+"}"

```
parm(in:&sdtPrueba);
```

Comment: si lo verifiqué y está correcto, arriba puse como tengo los parámetros. Ahora estoy viendo si es una combinación de " con ' en el body. No se que mas probar.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que no le está llegando el Header Content-Type:application/json. Por el casing de "Content-Type"?

Comment: ahora cambié  `&httpclient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')` por 
 `&httpclient.AddHeader('Content-type','application/json')`
y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Solucionado! Estaba haciendo `&httpclient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')` en el evento `start` y ejecutando el resto del código en un evento de usuario. Como estoy con GX15 el webpanel que estaba usando tiene la propiedad por defecto `Web User Experience=Smooth` y ejecuta el evento de usuario directo sin ejecutar el start. Gracias Gonzalo!

Answer (score 0):

le falta una doble comila "

--Dice:  &body='{"sdtPrueba":'+&sdtPrueba.ToJson().Trim()+"}"
--Debe decir:  &body='{"sdtPrueba":**"**'+&sdtPrueba.ToJson().Trim()+"}"